# Solution.java:28: error: missing return statement }

Tags: java

I am working this on Hacker Rank i am getting the error.
Question is :- Finding the sum of elements of array.

> Solution.java:28: error: missing return statement
>       }
>       ^ 1 error

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    /*
     * Complete the simpleArraySum function below.
     */
    static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];


       int sum =0;
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){

            sum+=sc.nextInt();

        }

    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int arCount = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());

        int[] ar = new int[arCount];

        String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        for (int arItr = 0; arItr < arCount; arItr++) {
            int arItem = Integer.parseInt(arItems[arItr].trim());
            ar[arItr] = arItem;
        }

        int result = simpleArraySum(ar);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

I am still a beginner.Sorry if this is a silly question but this is my first time on hacker rank.I tried searching online but i didn't got an solution so i asked it here.

Comment: Add `return sum;` just before the closing bracket in the function, `simpleArraySum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacktrace is saying you are missing return statement. Return the sum value. 
Further, this method also needs refactoring to add nums in input array.
I did like this:

```
static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {

            sum += ar[i];

        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Compiler Message
Runtime Error
Error (stderr)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Solution.simpleArraySum(Solution.java:14)
 at Solution.main(Solution.java:43)

Comment: can you share link for question?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum/problem?isFullScreen=true

Comment: @TECHWITHKEVAL the updated code runs green! but i suggest you to code with Cracking code interview or something before practicing hackerrank!

Answer (score 0):

add return statement

```
static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {
    int sum =0;
    int n = ar.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum+=ar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Gives Runtime error

Comment: static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {
     int sum =0;
     for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
      sum+=ar[i];
     }
     return sum;
    }

Comment: try the above code

Comment: how will i take the ar[] input?

Comment: this code doesn't work as it throws OutOfBoundException! :) tips: check for loop condition

Comment: you already getting input in the main class. and you are calling simpleArraySum and passing arr as argument.

Comment: sorry. add int n = ar.length; before for loop

Comment: still, this doesn't work! have tried and run it yourself?

Comment: actually your main function itself having error

Comment: nope! there isn't! :)

Comment: check my updated code. If you pass array of integers it will give sum. Its working